# In Flutter can I make the children of a DropdownButton a widget other than DropdownMenuItem

Tags: flutter, webview

I have a Flutter web app, which includes a web view on some pages.

I'm using the [PointerInterceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor) to prevent my web view from absorbing click events.

This works well,
but I have a situation now where I've got a `DropdownButton` and clicking it creates a bunch of `DropdownMenuItem`s - I want to wrap those items in the same `PointerInterceptor`, like this :

```dart
DropdownButton<dynamic>(
                items: myItems.map((e) => PointerInterceptor( child: DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: e,
                  child: Text(e.name),
                ))).toList(),
```

The problem is that this results in the following error :

> The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>?'.

But I have put my `DropdownButton` in the app bar, and the `DropdownMenuItems` are injected into the Widget tree directly under the `MaterialApp` widget, so there isn't a higher level widget I can wrap.

How can I use the PointerInterceptor widget when the DropdownButton expects `items` to be DropdownMenuItems?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the entire `DropdownButton` into `PointerInterceptor`?

Comment: Yes - but the DropdownButton itself only takes up the screen region of the button, whereas the DropdownMenuItems are created at a higher level in the widget tree (when the button is clicked) and they are outside the boxed region of the button.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by making another class that wrapped the `DropdownMenuItems` , and then use that as the `items` in the `DropdownButton` in its place.
(ie. replace `DropdownMenuItems` with `PointerInterceptedDropdownMenuItem`)

Here is the definition of my wrapper class :

```dart
class PointerInterceptedDropdownMenuItem<T> extends DropdownMenuItem {

  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final T? value;
  final bool enabled;

  const PointerInterceptedDropdownMenuItem({
    Key? key,
    this.onTap,
    this.value,
    this.enabled = true,
    AlignmentGeometry alignment = AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, alignment:alignment, child: child);

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PointerInterceptor( child: super.build(context) );
  }
}
```

**NB:** This is a good, tidy solution for the part of the question asking about having the children of a DropdownButton be other than a DropdownMenuItem,
but it is not a good solution for the specific part of wrapping the items in the PointerInterceptor class, and that is because having that many PointerInceptors (I have a long list) has a bad impact on performance, therefore the solution for that part will be to move the PointerInterceptor to the top level of the scaffold and then making it conditional, and updating some state (reflecting the dropdown list being open)to say if the PointerInterceptor should cover the whole screen or not.

Comment: Thanks for this. In order to get it to compile (I'm using Flutter 3.16.0 - maybe things have changed) I had to add the generic to DropdownMenuItem too ```class PointerInterceptedDropdownMenuItem<T> extends DropdownMenuItem<T>```